# Are there APIs for Android 9's Do Not Disturb Settings?

Tags: android

The Do Not Disturb settings have gotten a lot more customizable in Android 9. I love the range of settings it provides. But because of the number of options, it also takes a lot more time for me to set it up for different situations.

Are there and Java/Kotlin APIs for an app to turn on Do Not Disturb mode with the various settings? It would be nice if there could be a "profiles" like app that could turn on different previously saved configurations of DND mode at the tap of a button.